# Can you plot pure function without specifying variable?

Tags: plotting, pure-function

Given a pure function, e.g. `f=Sin[#]&`, it is possible to plot it with introducing an arbitrary local variable, e.g.,

```
Plot[f[x],{x,0,1}]
```

However, the introduction of a variable `x` seems unnecessary. Is it possible to plot this without specifying a name for the variable? If not, is there a good reason why this functionality doesn't exist?

Comment: AFAIK it only exists for `InterpolatingFunction`.

Comment: One could similarly ask why `Integrate[]` needs a dummy variable...

Comment: `myPlot[f_, r_] := Plot[f[First@r], r];
myPlot[f, {x, 0, 1}]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can plot it, but not using `Plot`. For example, you could map the function over a range of values and then use `ListLinePlot`:

```
With[{xmin = 0, xmax = 4π},
 ListLinePlot[f/@Subdivide[##,100],DataRange->{##}]&[xmin,xmax]
]
```

This uses the new function [`Subdivide`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide.html) with `100` plot points.

The reason why `Plot` requires you to specify a dummy variable is that it takes *expressions* and not *functions* as its argument. Therefore, the plot variable is not identifiable by a slot, and you need to specify it by naming the plot variable.

Comment: One of course loses out on the adaptive sampling of `Plot[]` in the process.

Comment: @J.M. Yes - but one person's loss is another person's gain - sometimes the sampling slows plotting down and you end up turning it off anyway...

Answer (score 13):

There is the function [`Unique`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unique.html), which is often used to avoid symbol name collisions.

You could use it like this:

```
Plot[f[#], {#, 0, 10}] &[Unique[]]
```

Of course, in another sense, it's the most arbitrary that a variable can get (it's just a variable with a name of the form `$12345` where 12345 represents some arbitrary number).

Comment: I can't help but feel that this is a cheat of sorts; you still specified a variable that just happened to be randomly generated.

Comment: @J.M. Sure, but I think it's often what people would want. For example, you might have a the function `f[a_] := D[a x^2, x] /. x -> 1` and not have access/be aware to the fact it is dependent on `x` internally, as it just looks like a simple mapping from a to f[a], but if you plot it with `x` you get a very different result to any other symbol.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is ***no***, not with `Plot`, which like many other *Mathematica* built-in functions that range over a set of values, is designed to follow a standard syntax pattern for which `Table` may be considered the prototype. Consider `Do` or even `Manipulate`$\text{*}$, which was added long after `Plot`. Both follow this pattern although in the case of `Manipulate` the semantics are wildly different.

$\text{*}$ See [this conference article](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/5758/) for a discussion of how `Manipulate` was deliberately designed to emulate `Table`. It also has many additional interesting things to say about `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 2):

As an additional small note to ciao's comment, it's possible to define your own function based on `Plot` to work with pure functions, e.g.:

```
plotPure[fun_, d_, args___] := 
    Plot[Evaluate@If[ListQ[fun], Through[fun[x]], fun[x]], {x, d[[1]], d[[2]]}, args];
```

This way it provides all `Plot` functionality:

```
plotPure[{Sin, Sin[#]^3 &}, {-Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle->"Thick"]
```